# Android Robolectric Unit tests are failing after adding databinding

Tags: android, unit-testing, data-binding, robolectric

I have Robolectric unit tests inflating an Activity like this :

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(BookActivity.class).withIntent(disputeIntent).create().get()
```

It was working fine until I changed to use databinding inflation on my activity from :

```
setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_book)
```

To

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_book);
```

I tried also this way of setting content view :

```
bindingView = ActivityBookBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(bindingView.getRoot());
```

but in both cases I am getting this error :

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/Dev/debug/layout/activity_book.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class layout

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
at com.package.name.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:56)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:276)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:261)
at com.package.name.BookActivity.onCreate(BookActivity.java:172)
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance